# putting marker having latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

this is my code :

button listener where i take a latitude and longitude and pass to other intent:

```
    find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent route = new Intent("com.project.simplify.MyLocationDemoActivity");

                    myAddress = "Vilnius, Kalvariju gatve 17";
                    System.out.println(myAddress);


                    try {
                        coder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                        address = coder.getFromLocationName(myAddress, 1);
                        //coder.getFromLocationName(myAddress,5);
                        if (address == null) {

                        }
                        Address location = address.get(0);
                       System.out.println( "lat : " + location.getLatitude());

                        System.out.println( "long : " + location.getLongitude());


                        float lat = (float) location.getLatitude();
                        float lng = (float) location.getLongitude();
                        route.putExtra("lat", lat);
                        route.putExtra("lng", lng);


                       startActivity(route);
                    }catch(Exception x){
                        System.out.println("nepavyko gauti koordinaciu + RouteActivity");
                    }
                }
            });
```

and other activity where i want to put marker

```
public class MyLocationDemoActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,
        OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GeoPoint gp;
    private LocationClient mLocationClient;
    private TextView mMessageView;

    // These settings are the same as the settings for the map. They will in
    // fact give you updates
    // at the maximal rates currently possible.
    private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
            .setInterval(5000) // 5 seconds
            .setFastestInterval(16) // 16ms = 60fps
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        float lng = (Float) intent.getSerializableExtra("lng");
        float lat = (Float) intent.getSerializableExtra("lat");
        setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
        mMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);


        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)));

    }
```

I pass the floats correctly, but cant find the way to add marker
what could be the problem ?

**UPDATE** still the same problem

```
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252): Process: com.project.simplify, PID: 11252
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.project.simplify/com.project.simplify.MyLocationDemoActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at com.project.simplify.MyLocationDemoActivity.onCreate(MyLocationDemoActivity.java:57)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-02 16:51:55.294: E/AndroidRuntime(11252):    ... 11 more
04-02 16:51:55.514: D/dalvikvm(11252): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 308K, 2% free 20060K/20400K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
04-02 16:51:55.674: W/ActivityThread(11252): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
```

Comment: they take double not floats

Comment: with floats also same problem

Comment: What is the code written on line 57 ?

Comment: i cant say now, i already changed the code

Comment: code : LatLng location = bundle.getParcelable("Location");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mMap` object in your case is not initialized! that's there reason for your `NullPointerException`.

In your `onCreate` method:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    float lng = (Float) intent.getSerializableExtra("lng");
    float lat = (Float) intent.getSerializableExtra("lat");
    setContentView(R.layout.my_location_demo);
    mMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)));
}
```

you have set the content view and you try to add a marker to the map straight away without getting it's instance first.

**UPDATE:**

You need to do something like this:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

before you can actually add marker to it.
I'm assuming that your added your map to your layout using the `SupportMapFragment` object.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to send Lat and Lng instead of marker in intent

//Sending LatLng in intent

```
intent in=new Intent(source.this,destination.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("Location", new LatLng(lat,lng));
in.putExtras(in);
startActivity(in);
```

//Receiving LatLng in other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
LatLng location = bundle.getParcelable("Location");
```